# Is this an energy or power signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, homework, signal-power, signal-energy

[image: signal]

Is the given input signal x[n] an energy or power signal?

The image shows what I did so far. Is it correct?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I solved it again, please tell me if I did it correctly this time.

$$E= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N = |4^nu[n]|$$
$$E= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1-4^{2(N+1)}}{1-4^2}$$
$$E=\infty$$

$$P= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{2N+1}\sum_{n=-N}^N = |4^nu[n]|$$
$$P= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{2N+1}(\frac{1-4^{2(N+1})}{1-4^2})$$
$$P=\infty$$

Since both P and E are infinite, then it is neither an energy or power signal.

Comment: are you sure you don't mean: $$ x[n] = 4^{-n} \ u[n] \qquad ? $$ >

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yep, I'm sure! It's really x[n] = 4^n u[n]. Did I solve it correctly?

Comment: @LaurentDuvalNoted! I retyped my edited solution using the math syntax :)

Comment: You possibly forgot squares in your summation terms. I have updated the answer for a simple proof for the energy part. This could provide guidelines for the power part

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to Matt's answer, on the intuition: $u[n]$ has value $1$ from $n=0$ on. So basically its energy will increase for ever, because it keeps adding ones for $n\ge0$. Then, you build another signal $x[n]$ that grows way faster because you multiply it with the exponential term $4^n$.

Therefore, only at the common sense level, one cannot expect it to be an energy signal. It is not feasible.

And then, goes the proof that the sum of the series actually diverges. I would suggest to use the simplest proofs, to avoid complexities, and formulae that are not valid (sum of geometric series for $a \ge1$).

$$\sum_{n=-N}^N  |4^nu[n]|^2 \ge \sum_{n=0}^N  4^{2n}|u[n]|^2\ge \sum_{n=0}^N  |u[n]|^2 \ge N+1$$
which diverges. Hence the signal is not energy. Something similar can be used for power.

Of course, as Matt said, if the  exponential term becomes $4^{-n}$, this geometrical series then decreases fast to zero, and wins over the mere sum of ones in $u[n]$.

Comment: +1, away from abstract math, back to common sense :)

Comment: Ohhh okay, thank you for this! Hopefully like you guys, I can call these things common sense too in the future :(

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to do some plausibility checks on your results. The energy of $x[n]$ is computed by summing up the values $|x[n]|^2$. Each one of these values is non-negative, so if you end up with a negative value for the signal energy, you should ask yourself where you went wrong (unless your name is [Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation)).

Check the conditions on the number $a$ for which your energy formula is valid. As a final note, if a signal is not an energy signal it is not necessarily a power signal.

Comment: Oh yea, thank you! It turns out I can't use it cause a should be less than 1 otherwise the answer would be negative :( But ugh now I'm really stuck. How should I proceed? @@

Comment: @Rose: Well, so the conclusion is that it's not an energy signal. Now use the definition of power and try to figure out if the power is finite or not.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure with my solution but so far, both of them are infinite! Does this mean it's neither an energy or power signal?

Comment: With all due respect to Srinivasa, Leonard and Daniel did it before http://eulerarchive.maa.org/hedi/HEDI-2006-06.pdf

Comment: @LaurentDuval: I believe that this is [controversial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#History), but anyway, those weird summations are usually called [Ramanujan summations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Ramanujan_summation), whoever came up with them first.

Comment: @Rose: If you've made sure that your result is correct, then that's indeed the only reasonable conclusion! Now you can ask yourself if there's no typo in the exercise ...

Comment: Sure, I learnt about Euler summation on the analytic continuation before I knew the name of Ramanujan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Euler_summation

Comment: @LaurentDuval: Yes, sometimes it seems that Euler did it all, and what he didn't do, Gauss did ...

Comment: And Poincaré cleaned  the room until Ramanujan emerged from the slum

Comment: @MattL. I included my new solution! Can you please check?

Comment: Both of you are so awesome @@

Comment: @Rose: Your conclusion is correct, even though you forgot to square the magnitudes.